# A variable that affects the dependent variable and is affected by another independent variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, confounding, exploratory-data-analysis, variable

I was analyzing happiness records data. One of the variables was trust in government and I hypothesized that this variable does not have an actual impact on the happiness score. I believe that this variable is affected by a third independent variable such as GDP per capita. I guess it's called confounding variable but I couldn't find a way to test this hypothesis. Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you experiment?

Comment: How can I experiment?

Comment: Can you set the variable and measure dependent?

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a little more information about your hypothesis, are you dealing with a dichotomous response variable, like if a disease is present or not? If so there is an empirical way to measure the possible confounding effect of the variable. See the link below.

[https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704-ep713_confounding-em/bs704-ep713_confounding-em_print.html#:~:text=Identifying%20Confounding,for%20a%20potential%20confounding%20factor.](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704-ep713_confounding-em/bs704-ep713_confounding-em_print.html#:%7E:text=Identifying%20Confounding,for%20a%20potential%20confounding%20factor.)

Some things to think about:
(1) If one variable does not have an effect on the response variable and could be correlated with another variable this could create issues with colinearity (or multicollinearity) because you are including a variable that may or may not be needed in your model. You can test for colinearity by calculating the variance inflation factor (VIF). If colinearity is present (VIF > 10 is generally recommended) this can result in greater 'inflated' residuals, poor predictions, and make it harder to assess if a variable is actually important or not (which may apply to your case)
(2) You may consider using an interaction term between the non-significant variable and possible confounding variable. The effect of the non-significant variable may be contingent on the value of the confounding variable.

It could be helpful to select variables in your model using a "best subset" variable selection criteria. I'm not sure what statistical analysis tool you are using, but most will have these features built-in.

Comment: Hey @Hunter M., I edited the hypothesis and dataset and provided more information about them.

Comment: Ok, this is an interesting question! You could include an interaction term in your model between trust in the government and per capita GDP because the effect of trust in the government could be dependent on per capita income like you are thinking. Then you can test for the significance of the interaction term. I would still test for collinearity using the VIF because that can really throw a wrench in your interpretations.